# Extract data from burp response and use in another request

Tags: kali-linux, jwt, burp-suite, ctf

I have a scenario where I need to call /api/login to get a token and then use said token in subsequent calls until it expires.

Is there a way to automate the call and token extraction and then to auto add it to the next requests?

I have tried making a macro and I can define a regex to get the token - but I can't seem to make it auto add to my next requests in the repeater.

I made a session rule to call the macro on each request, and it does get called but the token isn't being added

Comment: You should probably add the macro code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burp does not have a native functionality for that. You'll need to either write an Extension or use an existing one. I'd recommend [Token Extractor](https://portswigger.net/bappstore/f24211fa6fcd4bbea6b21f99c5cad27a).

Otherwise, you could also use Python for that. Proxy through localhost if you want to see the traffic in Burp. Do a regex parse (or json, if your data allows) and get the required token to use in the next request.